# Perl Parse rsync Output

Tags: regex, perl, statistics, rsync

Just a quick Perl question regarding rsync and parsing the stats output.

For example, stats such as the below are in a file:

```
Number of files: 14 (reg: 3, dir: 11)
Number of created files: 14 (reg: 3, dir: 11)
Number of deleted files: 0
Number of regular files transferred: 3
Total file size: 2,256,078 bytes
Total transferred file size: 2,256,078 bytes
Literal data: 2,256,078 bytes
Matched data: 0 bytes
File list size: 534
File list generation time: 0.001 seconds
File list transfer time: 0.000 seconds
Total bytes sent: 412
Total bytes received: 2,235,992

sent 412 bytes  received 2,235,992 bytes  894,561.60 bytes/sec
total size is 2,256,078  speedup is 1.01
```

My weakness begins with regex. I want to extract the information from the line:

```
Number of files: 14 (reg: 3, dir: 11)
```

I want to extract everything passed files: so `14 (reg: 3, dir:11)`.

I have tested this, but it's for the digits only and I can't for the life of me figure it out, I think I need to read up on regex more.

```
if($line =~ /Number of files:\s+(\d+)/){
    $numfiles=$1;
}
```

This only sets `$numfiles` as the first digit seen, 14.

If anyone can show me how to tackle this, that would be great.

Comment: Is [this](https://regex101.com/r/tA1pC3/1) what you are looking for ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would benefit from studying regular expressions more, and how to use capturing groups, but for this *specific* case, you'd probably want something like this.

```perl
if ($line =~ /^Number of files:\s+(\d+)\s+\(reg:\s+(\d+),\s+dir:\s+(\d+)\)/) {
    $numfiles = $1;
    $regfiles = $2;
    $dirfiles = $3;
}
```

Comment: thanks, this is strange, i tested it and it just bypasses that line in the file. removed the ^ at the beginning to make it like the original, still bypasses the line. Yet analyzing that, it makes perfect sense to me to match on that string.

Comment: Ok this works perfect, I noticed in the regex that it is bassed on (reg: XXX, dir: xxx) and i forgot previous I strip out all commas. Removing the , from the regex makes it work perfect! Thank you!

Comment: @John One note - you mentioned removing `^` before, I would suggest not doing that. Its presence makes it discard a lot of matches quickly, so it should perform better with `^`.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than just extracting a few fields from a single line, this will parse the entire block of output into a useful data structure. Each of the labels becomes a hash key, and for the special case of the first two lines, the sub-labels get appended to the main labels to form unique keys.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dump;

my %stats;

while (<DATA>) {
    last unless /\S/;
    chomp;
    my ($lhs, $rhs) = split(/: /, $_, 2);

    if ($rhs =~ /:/) {
        my @parts = split(/\W+/, $rhs);
        $rhs = shift(@parts);

        while (my ($key, $value) = splice(@parts, 0, 2)) {
            $stats{"$lhs - $key"} = $value;
        }
    }

    $stats{$lhs} = $rhs;
}

dd(\%stats);

__DATA__
Number of files: 14 (reg: 3, dir: 11)
Number of created files: 14 (reg: 3, dir: 11)
Number of deleted files: 0
Number of regular files transferred: 3
Total file size: 2,256,078 bytes
Total transferred file size: 2,256,078 bytes
Literal data: 2,256,078 bytes
Matched data: 0 bytes
File list size: 534
File list generation time: 0.001 seconds
File list transfer time: 0.000 seconds
Total bytes sent: 412
Total bytes received: 2,235,992

sent 412 bytes  received 2,235,992 bytes  894,561.60 bytes/sec
total size is 2,256,078  speedup is 1.01
```

Output:

```
{
  "File list generation time"           => "0.001 seconds",
  "File list size"                      => 534,
  "File list transfer time"             => "0.000 seconds",
  "Literal data"                        => "2,256,078 bytes",
  "Matched data"                        => "0 bytes",
  "Number of created files"             => 14,
  "Number of created files - dir"       => 11,
  "Number of created files - reg"       => 3,
  "Number of deleted files"             => 0,
  "Number of files"                     => 14,
  "Number of files - dir"               => 11,
  "Number of files - reg"               => 3,
  "Number of regular files transferred" => 3,
  "Total bytes received"                => "2,235,992",
  "Total bytes sent"                    => 412,
  "Total file size"                     => "2,256,078 bytes",
  "Total transferred file size"         => "2,256,078 bytes",
}
```

Comment: This is very instructive, thanks, I will see if I can work with it to read the full output of rsync and only start where the stats start in the file. At the beginning of the file is lot of lines about what files being transferred etc.

Comment: @John Give it a shot, and if you run into a problem you can't solve, ask a new question. Also, please see: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)