# Parse rsync stats, line Number of files with bash only

Tags: regex, bash, parsing, grep, rsync

I need to parse rsync stats like:

```
Number of files: 265 (reg: 189, dir: 10, link: 66)
Number of created files: 18
Number of deleted files: 4
Number of regular files transferred: 24
Total file size: 121.67K bytes
Total transferred file size: 0 bytes
Literal data: 0 bytes
Matched data: 0 bytes
File list size: 0
File list generation time: 0.001 seconds
File list transfer time: 0.000 seconds
Total bytes sent: 9.15K
Total bytes received: 33

sent 9.15K bytes received 33 bytes 18.37K bytes/sec
total size is 121.67K speedup is 13.24
```

Parsing each line is rather easy using commands like this:

```
$(echo "$rawstats" | grep -Po '(?<=Number of files: ).*')
```

Now I need to parse the first line. I found a Perl solution here: [Perl Parse rsync Output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35192307/perl-parse-rsync-output)
but I don't want to rely on perl and Dan Lowe answer won't work in all cases since what's in () could be any combination of reg:, dir:, link: (and even other I ignore).
I.e :

```
265 (reg: 189, dir: 10, link: 66)
265 (dir: 10, link: 66)
265 (link: 66)
```

So I'm trying to build the right regex to pass to grep -P
So far I found :

```
(\d+) \((?:([a-z]+): (\d+)(?:, )?)*\)?
```

Which is matching like this:

```
[0] is a null string
[1]=265
[2]=link
[3]=66
```

The result I expected :

```
[1]=265
[2]=reg
[3]=189
[4]=dir
[5]=10
[6]=link
[7]=66
```

I can't see how to improve my result.
An even best result would be a bash associative array like :

```
[reg]=189
[dir]=10
[link]=66
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Pure Bash with Grep

I see no reason to avoid Perl, which is quite convenient when it comes to text parsing. But here is a pure Bash implementation that produces an associative array `stats` out of `rawstats` variable containing the rsync stats output:

```sh
declare -A stats=()

label_regex='Number of files:'
num_of_files_line=$(grep -E "$label_regex" <<< "$rawstats")

regex="$label_regex ([0-9]+)"
[[ $num_of_files_line =~ $regex ]] && stats['total']=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}

while read -r k v; do stats["$k"]="$v"; done < <( \
    regex='([a-z]+): ([0-9]+)'
    while [[ $num_of_files_line =~ $regex ]]; do
        match=${BASH_REMATCH[0]}
        printf "%s %s\n" "${BASH_REMATCH[1]} ${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
        num_of_files_line=${num_of_files_line#*"$match"}
    done
)
```

Process substitution (`<( ... )`) allows to use the `stats` variable within the loop. Pipes would create sub-shells which do not share variables.

#### Perl

And here is a similar Perl implementation which I would probably use:

```sh
declare -A stats=()
while read -r k v; do stats["$k"]="$v"; done < <( \
  printf "%s\n" "$rawstats" | \
    perl -ne '/Number of files: (\d+)/ or next; print "total $1\n"; print "$1 $2\n" while (/([a-z]+): (\d+)/g)' \
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using any awk in any shell on every UNIX box:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS="[(): ,]+" }
sub(/^Number of files: [0-9]+ /,"") {
    for (i=2; i<NF; i+=2) {
        printf "[%s]=%d\n", $i, $(i+1)
    }
    exit
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
[reg]=189
[dir]=10
[link]=66
```

You can tweak that output to populate a bash associative array with it if you like (google it).

Answer (score 0):

looks like your requirement has changed... (gawk specific) `zalem.awk`:

```
BEGIN {
  FS="[(),:]"
}
/^Number of files:/ {
  for(i=2;i<NF;i++)
    printf("[%d]=%s\n", i-1, gensub(/[[:space:]]/, "","g",$i))
}
```

Answer (score -1):

something along these lines - a little bit verbose, but..
`echo "$rawstats" | awk -f zalem.awk` where zalem.awk is:

```
BEGIN {
  FS="[()]"
}
/^Number of files:/ {
  np=split($2, npA,/, */)
  gsub(/[^0-9]/,"",$1)
  for(i=1;i<=np;i++) {
     printf("%s (", $1)
     for(j=i;j<=np;j++)
        printf("%s%s%s", (j==i)?"":" ", npA[j], (j==np)?")"ORS:",")
  }
}
```

yields:

```
 265  (reg: 189, dir: 10, link: 66)
 265  (dir: 10, link: 66)
 265  (link: 66)
```